# Can I accept file uploads using the Craft Guest Entries plugin?

Tags: assets, form, guest

Can I accept file uploads using the Craft Guest Entries plugin? Using input type="file" doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see why you couldn't. That is unless the plugin needs to handle file uploads as opposed to the Entry Model.

Take a look at [Uploading Files from a Form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields#uploading-files-from-front-end-entry-forms). You need to make sure your form tag has `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and your file input has the name `fields[fieldHandle]`. If you are uploading multiple files, be sure to add and extra set of square braces on the end (`fields[fieldHandle][]`).

Comment: I’m 90% sure you are right.